# How do I include XML in an email body using mailmessage.body

Tags: c#, xml, email, mailmessage

I have an application that performs some tests. As a result of these tests an XML object is produced (from an XmlDiff compare).
Is there any way to embed the XML into an Email body in a formatted state?
I am using XmlWriter to a StringBuilder object then converting the string into and "html safe" format using System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(). In the MailMessage, I set IsBodyHtml = true.
To extract the XML I want to embed:

```
        public static string GetDiff(string approvedfile, string failingfile)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XmlWriter xmlwriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
        XmlDiff xdiff =
            new XmlDiff(XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreChildOrder | XmlDiffOptions.IgnoreNamespaces |
                        XmlDiffOptions.IgnorePrefixes);
        bool response = xdiff.Compare(approvedfile, failingfile, false, xmlwriter);
        xmlwriter.Flush();
        xmlwriter.Close();
        return System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(sb.ToString());
    }
```

To set the body content I am using:

```
        string sb = GetDiff(approvedMapfile, fileout);
        string message = String.Format("Comparison of Map item1 and Map item2 for {0} failed.</br>Review the differences here:</br>{1}</br> and Compare the files</br>{2}</br>and</br>{3}</br>to find the differences.", loc, sb, emailApprovedMap, emailFailedMap);
        Util.SendStatusEmail(message);
```

in SendStatusEmail the mail information is being set thusly:

```
        public static string SendStatusEmail(string status)
    {
        string hostServer = "smtphost.this.server.com";

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 25;
        client.Host = hostServer;
        client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("me@here.com", "Me There");
        mail.From = from;
        mail.To.Add("You@there.com");
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Body = status;
        mail.Subject = "Map Checker status report";
        try
        {
            client.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

When the email is received using the above methodology, the embedded XML is included, but it is not formatted, it appears as one long string of XML.
Is there a way to programmatically embed XML in an email body and have it appear as formatted?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should use a [XmlWriterSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the creation of your writer.

Comment: U could just add it as a .xml file in the email.attachments?

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, and I am doing that already. The preference is to have it in the body though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @tschmit007: Thanks, I will look more closely at XmlWriterSettings.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, in the last of the body message create one div and set style display none, not insert close div only open tag div with style display none.

Answer (score 0):

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
```

does the job, unless you really need html formatted body.

Comment: Thanks, but I did need HTML formatting. I ended up staying with the XML as an attachment. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is too old but i have solution to just encode the xml text.

refer how to do on C#: [How to encode the ampersand if it is not already encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722783/how-to-encode-the-ampersand-if-it-is-not-already-encoded)

Basically having lib to do this:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string)
```

i'm doing with java something like this:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4("<xml><row>1</row></xml>");
```